# Python convert QByteArray into bytes

Tags: python, qt

i'm looking to convert data stored into QByteArray to bytes format, dont't find any method of QBytesArray class doing that, any idea??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Its `QByteArray.data()`

```
b = QtCore.QByteArray(b'123')
b.data()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, no details about data() in the doc !